# FormPage Selection List Not Displaying Value

Tags: formpage

In using `FormPage[]` to select an item from a list with the default layout, an item is selected but the choice is not displayed.  I have tried numerous options but to no avail.  As you can see below, the code works properly, displaying the selected string in reverse, but the selector does not display the name chosen.  Am I using the wrong function or is there a way to get `FormPage[]` to display the item selected from the list?

```
names = {"Alice", "Andy", "Jane", "John"};
FormPage[{"name" -> names}, StringReverse[#name] &]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the control explicitly as `PopupMenu[#, names]&` it works:

```
FormPage["name"-> <|"Interpreter"->names,  "Control" -> (PopupMenu[#, names]&)|>,   
  StringReverse[#name] &]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr how did you create the animation?

Comment: @Lee, I use the  [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) app.

Comment: Looks very handy, thx.